# Different Map-View sizes between 2 activities

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have 2 activities that contains `MapView`. 
In activity A mapview have different size then in activity B.
The call hirarchy is `Activity` A -> `Activity` B.
When I'm returning from `Activity` B to A the half of the map is black (only Google sign remains in left corner).
Moving map has no effect (bottom of the map is still black) only zoom in/out makes map looks properly.

In android manifest I use different ID's, 
I've tried `invalidate()` mapview in `onResume()` method,
I've tried to call `findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout()` on whole layout also in `onResume()`with no effect. 
The only solution was to `finish()` activity `onPause()` and create it again on keyback in activity B.
Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Congrats your question got "featured" in a SO blog post :)
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/11/get-rid-of-ads-you-dont-like-and-encourage-ads-you-do-like/?cb=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see in your LogCat that the Activities are reusing the undelaying Map:

```
MapActivity: Recycling map object
```

To restore your old settings in the map use the onResume method on both activities:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    MapController mapController = mMapView.getController();

    mapController.setCenter(mCenterPoint);
    mapController.setZoom(mZoomLevel);
    mapController.animateTo(mCenterPoint);
}
```

As onCreate will only be called once and the back button or new Intent will (hopefully) reuse the actual Intent on the stack.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I've been looking for but after @Egor explanation, your solution: do the job as one of 'workarounds'. Thank you

Comment: Did it work for you? I moved all the initialisation of `MapView` and `MapController` to `onResume()`, but I still have this weird behaviour you described (although in my case half of the map is grey, not black:P)

Comment: Did the first map showed right the first time, before calling the second one?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Google Maps API won't let you have several instances of `MapView` active on the same time. When you open `Activity` B from `Activity` A, `Activity` A still stays in stack and its `MapView` is still working. So when you instantiate another `MapView` in `Activity` B, the older one starts to behave abnormally. There are several workarounds, but none of them can be considered stable, so you should go with your solution of destroying and recreating `Activity` A, or redesign your application such that only one of your `Activities` uses `MapView`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The most probably cause it that you instantiate the map `onCreate` method, so the first time the map shows fine, but when you come back the `onCreate` method didn't be called and your map isn't initiated.
Move the map initialization to the `onStart` method.

Maybe [the Activity lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) can help

PS: if you post your code will be easy help you.